# NetBeans debug not working for phpunit tests

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, xdebug

I followed  [Rafael Dohms's article](http://blog.rafaeldohms.com.br/2011/05/13/debugging-phpunit-tests-in-netbeans-with-xdebug/) to use NetBeans debugging tools for phpunit tests.

The problem is when I start debugging in NetBeans and run test using command line, NetBeans switches from "waiting for connection" state to "netbeans-xdebug runnig". But program stops at command line after "cofiguration read from ..." and also none of debug actions(Step over, Step into etc) are active.

I tried to disable "Stop at first line" option and also using debug file for debuging, but none of them worked.

Did I miss something in configuration or using NetBeans tools?

**update**

I tried to fix the problem using NetBeans but it didn't work. finally I used PhpStrom to debug the code, although I got same result, I succeed to debug normal CLI program and also tracking my phpunit test program. I realized that debugging freezes in "pear\PHPUnit\Util\PHP.php" file, in the following line:

```
$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
```

I'm using Windows 7 and php-v5.3

Comment: Can you debug when executing some PHP from commandline? Because really thats what Netbeans does.

Comment: Same result; except this time the file executed completely, but never stops in any breakpoints

Comment: What OS are you using? Debugging works in the browser?

Comment: Same problem here, did you solved it?

Answer (score 4):

Found this post when searching for the line

```
$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
```

in combination with keywords xdebug and phpunit.

I got stuck with equal symptoms, phpstorm (never tried netbeans) eventually led me to this line stalling.

During stepping to this line I noticed some mentions of 'process isolation', which made me drop the --process-isolation parameter in my xdebug call (this in itself we use to workaround a memory leak). Now the bugging line does not get called, and normal xdebug/unittest operation continiue's

Not claiming this to be a solution, but at least was a workable workaround for me. Also might give some direction to actually problem/solution

Comment: How did you drop the process-isolation parameter?

Comment: iirc it was just a CLI parameter in a manual CLI phpunit with xdebug  run.. Ommitting the parameter is a matter of just not typing it ;) I think the process isolation might also be a setting somewhere in phpunit.xml but i did not use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have installed Xdebug on Webserver, usually listening on port 9000.

Check this blog post how to configure Xdebug http://bogdan-albei.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/php-remote-debugging-with-xdebug-and.html

From what you wrote it seems to me that Xdebug doesn't work.

Comment: I had problem running xdebug on port 9000, so I switched it to port 9003 and then it worked fine.
Also cli and webserver could be using different php.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have debug setting is both apache2 and cli php.ini

I add the following entry into both these files

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be using the *strict* mode in phpunit, e.g. in `phpunit.xml`.

Because of this setting stopping at a breakpoint triggers a timeout. Without strict mode no timeouts are active.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and nowhere found a correct solution but now I debug my test cases. I hope this short "how to" will be helpful for you also.

When you debugging in browser there only differents in the $_SERVER superglobals so first of all you need this.

Just throw an Exception in your test case for examle:

`throw new Exception(json_encode($_SERVER));`

If everything ok then you will see something like this in your test error message:

`{"ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\ProgramData","APPDATA":"C:\User......`

create a file (for example named: "`phpunit-debug._SERVER.json`") and copy-paste full json line into this file.

second, you have to make a "phpunit-debug.php" file with this content:

`$_SERVER = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents("phpunit-debug._SERVER.json"));
// include your bootstrap if it's necessary...
include 'c:\xampp\php\phpunit';  // TADAA! your PHPUnit tricked and believe
                                 // that you called by NetBeans ;) but can
                                 // debugging with xdebug as usually`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps things have changed, but I was in no way able to initiate the connection from terminal when running phpunit with Netbeans 8.1 after trying each of the previous answers here. At best it would just say in the nb console, run... done. Never any waiting for connection.

What did work for me was to initiate it from Netbeans.

Here's some instructions that worked for me on **Ubuntu 16.04** *assuming php and netbeans are already installed and working*.

1. Install the xdebug extension

   ```
   sudo apt install php-xdebug
   ```
2. Enable it

   ```
   sudo phpenmod xdebug
   ```
3. Add environment variables to `php.ini` or `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

   ```
   zend_extension=xdebug.so
   xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
   xdebug.remote_enable= On
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.remote_mode=req
   xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
   xdebug.remote_port=9000
   ```
4. I require phpunit in my project as a [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) dev dependency, so the executable is located at `vendor/bin/phpunit` and this is the file to set as the **"Index File"**
5. I use a [`phpunit.xml` configuration file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) to set options and test suites in my project root folder. So you need to set that directory location as the **"Working Directory"** so that it picks up your bootstrap etc.

[image: screenshot netbeans project properties]